# Sorting only if condition applies - std::sort

Tags: c++, sorting, std

Say I have to sort a football league table by points and if the number of points are equal between two teams, sort them by the goals difference.

Using `std::sort` with a functor I successfully sorted the table by points. but how do I now sort the teams which have similar points *only*?

In other words, I need to somehow use sort and make it sort only the teams which have similar number of points. Is there any comfortable way to do that?

Comment: Just put both conditions in your `operator<`.  Example : `return std::tie(points, goals) < std::tie(other.points, other.goals);`

Comment: wont it just sort it by goal difference now then?

Comment: What do u mean by *teams which have similar points ONLY*? What happens to the rest?

Comment: I quote @Ranveer: what happens to the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comparison function, first return `true` if `lhs.points < rhs.points`. Then return `false` if `rhs.points < lhs.points`. If you've gotten to this point, you know the points are equal (if not, the function has already returned), so you can just return `lhs.goals < rhs.goals`.

Comment: Ok I got it. but just for general knowledge, is it possible to sort between two items only if a condition applies?

Comment: @Rouki: I don't know what you mean by that, please clarify it a bit.

Comment: Lets say the vector is fully sorted by points. Now I want that std::sort will only swap (If needed) between those with similar points and different goals-difference

Comment: @Rouki: Not with a single call to `sort`. You could do it with a loop though. Start with an iterator to the beginning of the vector, then use [`std::upper_bound`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/upper_bound) in order to find the end of the range of elements with equal points values, then sort that range (using a comparator that only looks at goals). Then repeat the process starting the search from the end of the previous range, and keep repeating until you get to the end of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

Overload the operator `<`

```
bool operator < (const team& A, const team& B) //team is a struct of points and goals
{
    if (A.points != B.points) return (A.points < B.points);
    else return (A.goals < B.goals);
}
```